# Как в java сделать сортировку строк по алфавиту?

Tags: java

Собственно не понятно как сортировать строки по алфавиту

Comment: Где строки находятся? В массиве?

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у вас список `wordsList` с объектами `String`:

```
Collections.sort(wordsList);
```

Если у вас массив `wordsArray` с объектами `String`:

```
Arrays.sort(wordsArray);
```

Если у вас строка со словами, и вы хотите отсортировать слова в строке в алфавитном порядке, то вы можете использовать способ с массивом сверху, предварительно создав массив из строки: `String[] wordsArray = "Строка со словами тут находится".split(" ");`

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.*; 

ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    abc.add("C"); 
    abc.add("A"); 
    abc.add("B"); 
Collections.sort(abc);
```